# Spring: change EntityManager dynamically

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

for some reason the database (**ugly!**) that I should use contains all the tables twice; every table are duplicated into these modes: `DB1_<table>` and `DB2_<table>`.

The structures of these databases **are the same**!

The application that I am realizing uses Spring + Hibernate and should permit to the users to **change** the database on **runtime**; this mean that a user can start the application using database DB1 and after some minutes change to DB2, return to DB1 and so on.

I have tried to extend `DefaultNamingStrategy` for every databases:

```
// I have create also DB2
public class DB1 extends DefaultNamingStrategy {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 676544180324515651L;

    @Override
    public String tableName(String tableName) {
        return "DB1_" + tableName;
    }

}
```

and set the naming strategy through the property `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy` of jpa **dinamically** but for a reason that I can't understand I can change the naming strategy only once, and all next callings trown an Exception.

Someone know why?

Configuration of **entityManagerFactory**:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="it.perfectquiz.entity" />
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

How I try to change naming strategy:

```
    XmlWebApplicationContext context = (XmlWebApplicationContext) ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
    DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) context.getBeanFactory();
    GenericBeanDefinition entityManager = (GenericBeanDefinition) beanFactory.getBeanDefinition("entityManagerFactory");
    ManagedProperties jpaProperties = (ManagedProperties) entityManager.getPropertyValues().get("jpaProperties");
    TypedStringValue namingStrategy = (TypedStringValue) jpaProperties.get(new TypedStringValue("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy"));

    // only for test!
    String newNaming;
    if (namingStrategy.getValue().equals(DB1.class.getCanonicalName()))
        newNaming = DB2.class.getCanonicalName();
    else
        newNaming = DB1.class.getCanonicalName();
    // only for test!

    namingStrategy.setValue(newNaming);

    beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("entityManagerFactory", entityManager);
```

Thanks,

Regards

Comment: "for some reason". Yeah, I know how this is :-)

Comment: Instead of one EntityManager that tries to change personality, why not have 2 different EntityManagers, and make the app use one or the other?